# Who sets a thread's IsAlive property?

Tags: multithreading

When a thread starts, who decides the status of thread; whether it is alive or dead?

Comment: Please specify what kind of threads you're talking about. There are many threading libraries out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said, but I'm assuming that you're referring to the [Thread.IsAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive.aspx) property in .NET.

This property is set automatically by the framework itself. Basically, when you go `Thread.Start()`, the framework runs a bit of code that sets up the thread to be ready to run (including setting `IsAlive` to `true`), opens a `try...catch` block and calls your delegate. When your delegate returns (or an exception is thrown) there is more code inside the framework that executes to tear down the thread (and set `IsAlive` to `false`).